# jQuery function as a string with arguments as Array (JavaScript "apply()" equivalent for jQuery elements)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments

I would like to call a jQuery function into a jQuery plugin, with its name as a string, and its arguments as an object (Array).
I'm looking for a kind of equivalent to the JavaScript "apply" function in jQuery.

I had to find a workaround, but it's really dirty and limited. Here it is :

```
//funcName is the name of the function I want to call
//funcArgs is an Array of arguments
//$(this) is a jQuery element
switch(funcArgs.length) {
    case 1:
        $.fn[funcName] && $(this)[funcName](funcArgs[0]);
        break;
    case 2:
        $.fn[funcName] && $(this)[funcName](funcArgs[0], funcArgs[1]);
        break;
    //...
    default:
        $.fn[funcName] && $(this)[funcName]();
}
```

Could you please help me to make it unlimited ? (Without any switch...)

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is a *library*, not a language. The language you're using is JavaScript, and so `apply` is exactly what you want:

```
var $this = $(this);
$this[funcName].apply($this, funcArgs);
```

Or

```
$.fn[funcName].apply($(this), funcArgs);
```

...since `$.fn` is the prototype underlying jQuery instances.

Comment: My post was not clear enough. I know jQuery is a library and JavaScript a language, but I didn't know how to use "apply" with it. You perfectly answered me! Thank you very much.